# Need to select 'Do not store password.' Option in Task Scheduler w/PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, security, scheduled-tasks, password-protection

I am trying to schedule a task using PowerShell because it allows the use of wild cards and command prompts do not. I have the script to create the task to run an .exe file, the issue I am having is I need to have '**Do Not Store Password. The task will only have access to local resources**' selected. Not sure how to have that executed within the script. This what I have:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /F /SC weekly /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN /TN "PROGRAM" /ST 17:00 /TR "cmd /c start C:\<FOLDER>\<FILE PATH FOLDER>\<PROGRAM>.exe" /RU system
```

I have tried multiple things, nothing of relevance as I am desperate to get any type of result. My goal is to just have the box selected.

[image]

Comment: This is not a Powershell script. Powershell uses the `New-ScheduledTask` cmdlet - see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/

Comment: you are correct, the script that I am using is to schedule a task using a batch file. I used PowerShell to create the task because it allows wildcards.

Comment: `SCHTASKS.exe`, as an _external program_, is independent of any shell, so it can equally be called from `cmd.exe` or PowerShell. While your question is ultimately only about `SCHTASKS.exe`, the syntax of its _invocation_ can vary by shell, notably with respect to quoting styles and environment-variable references. I've left the `powershell` tag, based on the body of your question, but your comment confuses me: if the `SCHTASKS.exe` call is made _from a batch file_, the `cmd` / `batch-file` tags should be used. Is it? As shown, the call would work from either shell.

Answer (score 0):

- You're using **`/ru system`**, which means that your scheduled task runs as the **built-in 
  `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account**, in which case **NO password is stored along with the task** - irrespective of what the GUI may suggest. (That built-in account doesn't even *have* a password).
  The same applies to `/ru localservice` (`NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`) and
  `/ru networkservice` (`NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`)
- If you want to **run as the *current user* without storing a password**, omit the `/ru` argument and **use `/np` instead**.

  - If you want to run as a *different* (non-system) user, add `/ru $someUser`.
    Note that in combination with `/np` you *will* be prompted for that user's password, but solely to authorize *creating* the task; the password isn't *stored*.

Note the **implications of using `/ru system` , `/ru localservice` , `/ru networkservice`  or `/np`**:

- The task runs *whether or not someone is logged on*.
- It always runs *invisibly*.
- It only has access to *local* resources (no network access), *except* with `/ru networkservice`, which "presents the *computer*'s credentials to remote servers. By default, the remote token contains SIDs for the `Everyone` and `Authenticated Users` groups" (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account), emphasis added).

Conversely, the **implications of *not* using `/ru` or using `/ru` as a non-system user and specifying *neither* `/np` *nor* `/rp`** (which implies `/it`) are:

- The task runs *only* when the target user is logged on, and *no* password need be stored.
- If the target user is logged on when the task tries to run, it runs *visibly*.
- The task runs with the target user's usual privileges.

  - *If* the target user is an administrator, you can request that the task run *with elevation*, by adding **`/rl HIGHEST`**. You'll get *no* error message if the target user *isn't* an administrator, even though that means that the argument is effectively ignored.

Only if you want non-system **users to run tasks with their *usual privileges* and *invisibly, whether or not someone is logged on*** do you need to **store a password**:

- Use **`/rp *`** to trigger a password prompt (you may also pass the password directly, but that is ill-advised for security reasions).
- Since `/rp` *must be combined with `/ru`*, add `/ru $env:USERNAME` in order to target the *current* user.
- Optionally, to request that the task run *elevated*, add `/rl HIGHEST` (assuming the target user is an administrator).

See also:

- The [`schtasks.exe` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks)

---